# How to add error trap on my code that would ignore a null value extracted from my ms Access Database?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

How can i make an error trap that would ignore any null value extracted from ms access database)?

i want my program to just ignore any null value returned and just continue as i don't have a problem for a blank data to be showed on my form.

in this code, the error highlights
    .SubItems(6) = rs3!Regularization_Date

because Regularization_Date is blank on my databse. i want my program to just ignore this one and continue filling out my listview with all the data there is to show.

```
 Private Function SearchData()

Result.Show

Result.ListView1.ListItems.Clear
Sql = "SELECT * FROM All_Employees WHERE ID LIKE '" & (Text1.Text) & "'"

Set rs3 = New ADODB.Recordset
rs3.Open Sql, con3, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
If Not rs3.EOF Then
 Do Until rs3.EOF
Set lst1 = Result.ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , rs3!ID)

    With lst1

     .SubItems(1) = rs3!Lastname
     .SubItems(2) = rs3!FirstName
     .SubItems(3) = rs3!Position
    .SubItems(4) = rs3!Date_hired
    .SubItems(5) = rs3!Employment_Status
    *.SubItems(6) = rs3!Regularization_Date*
    .SubItems(7) = rs3!Office_email
    .SubItems(8) = rs3!Shift_Start
    .SubItems(9) = rs3!Shift_End
    End With
rs3.MoveNext
Loop


End If
Set rs3 = Nothing
End Function
```

i just want an errortrap that would ignore all null values.

Comment: I've seen folks do something like this: `.SubItems(6) = rs3!Regularization_Date & ""` -- turning the null into a null string. No idea if it will solve your issue but it seems to work for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to ignore the error, you could use On Error Resume Next

```
Private Function SearchData()

Result.Show

Result.ListView1.ListItems.Clear
Sql = "SELECT * FROM All_Employees WHERE ID LIKE '" & (Text1.Text) & "'"

**On Error Resume Next**

Set rs3 = New ADODB.Recordset
rs3.Open Sql, con3, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
If Not rs3.EOF Then
 Do Until rs3.EOF
Set lst1 = Result.ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , rs3!ID)

    With lst1

     .SubItems(1) = rs3!Lastname
     .SubItems(2) = rs3!FirstName
     .SubItems(3) = rs3!Position
    .SubItems(4) = rs3!Date_hired
    .SubItems(5) = rs3!Employment_Status
    *.SubItems(6) = rs3!Regularization_Date*
    .SubItems(7) = rs3!Office_email
    .SubItems(8) = rs3!Shift_Start
    .SubItems(9) = rs3!Shift_End
    End With
rs3.MoveNext
Loop


End If
Set rs3 = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the IsNull function to check the value in the field.
It would look something like this:

```
.SubItems(1) = rs3!Lastname
.SubItems(2) = rs3!FirstName
.SubItems(3) = rs3!Position
.SubItems(4) = rs3!Date_hired
.SubItems(5) = rs3!Employment_Status
if not IsNull(rs3!Regularization_Date) then
    .SubItems(6) = rs3!Regularization_Date
end if
.SubItems(7) = rs3!Office_email
.SubItems(8) = rs3!Shift_Start
.SubItems(9) = rs3!Shift_End
```

You can find more information here [IsNull Docs on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnull-function)

If you really wanted it in an error handler you could do it like this:

```
Private Function SearchData()

    on error goto ErrHandler:
    Result.Show
    Result.ListView1.ListItems.Clear
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM All_Employees WHERE ID LIKE '" & (Text1.Text) & "'"

    Set rs3 = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs3.Open Sql, con3, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    If Not rs3.EOF Then
    Do Until rs3.EOF
        Set lst1 = Result.ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , rs3!ID)

        With lst1
            .SubItems(1) = rs3!Lastname
            .SubItems(2) = rs3!FirstName
            .SubItems(3) = rs3!Position
            .SubItems(4) = rs3!Date_hired
            .SubItems(5) = rs3!Employment_Status
            .SubItems(6) = rs3!Regularization_Date
            .SubItems(7) = rs3!Office_email
            .SubItems(8) = rs3!Shift_Start
            .SubItems(9) = rs3!Shift_End
        End With
        rs3.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

Cleanup:
    Set rs3 = Nothing

    exit function

ErrHandler:
    dim intErrNo    as integer
    dim strErrMsg   as string

    intErrNo = Err.Number
    strErrMsg = Err.Description

    if intErrNo = 94 then
        'Null Value continue with the next line of the code
        resume next
    else
        MsgBox "Error Number: " & intErrNo & vbCrLF & "Description : " & strErrMsg
        GoTo CleanUp
    end if

End Function
```

You modify the error handling to display what you want, or just log the error.
Just as a suggestion, you could change the function to a sub because you aren't returning anything.